# Apply button 'Active' styles on keypress in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a drum app in React/Redux that's fully functional as it stands, but I want to be able to apply the active button style when the corresponding keypress is made just like it does when I physically click the button. As it stands, clicking the button does a transition but typing the corresponding key just plays the audio file, and isn't really linked to the button. Is there a way to mark the corresponding button active on keypress?

Heres my CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/k29r3928z7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect use case to use [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) (as the documentation says, do not abuse its use).

For each button, you need a "ref"(erence) to the DOM element. When you press a key and you find its code in your json, you will access the corresponding reference to the button and trigger the "focus" method, to indicate the UI that the button was somehow pressed.

Your button definition should look something like this:

```
{drumObj.map(x => (
      <button
        className="drum-pad"
        ref={"drumButton" + x.trigger}
        key={x.id}
        id={x.id}
        onClick={() => drumHit(x.url, x.id)}
      > ...
```

We set a ref name for each button dynamically (try to find a way to define a unique ref name prefix in your component and define it only in one place), based on the char it represents. Once we have the references stored, we access them as needed in the **handleKeyPress** method like this:

```
handleKeyPress = event => {
   const drumKey = drumObj.find(obj => obj.keyCode === event.keyCode);

   if (drumKey) {
     this.refs["drumButton" + drumKey.trigger].focus();
     this.props.drumHit(drumKey.url, drumKey.id);
   }
};
```

I would actually replace the call to **this.props.drumHit(...)** for:

```
this.refs["drumButton" + drumKey.trigger].click();
```

The reason for that is because if you change the **drumHit** method name or signature in the future, you just need to update it in the onClick property of your button properties definition. As a good practice, always try to emulate this kind of events programmatically, instead of replicate the same behavior in different parts of your code.

So your **handleKeyPress** method should look something like this:

```
handleKeyPress = event => {
   const drumKey = drumObj.find(obj => obj.keyCode === event.keyCode);

   if (drumKey) {
     this.refs["drumButton" + drumKey.trigger].click();
     this.refs["drumButton" + drumKey.trigger].focus();
   }
};
```

I hope it helps!

Regards,
Max.

Comment: this shifts focus to the button but doesn't trigger the transition i.e. before...after. Is there any way to do that in addition to what you've said? I appreciate the extra information as well!

Comment: I just figured it out! I changed my css to focus:after and then added a .blur() call to transition focus away from the element as soon as it was pressed.

Comment: That is the way to go. You added the needed style and emulated the action. Congrats! ;)