# How do I make ReactJS button look like pressed on keyPress?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

I created a Drum Machine with ReactJS, and I can't find a way to make the buttons look like clicked when I press the corresponding key. I found the following question on the site, but I can't make refs work with my code and I don't know why:

[Apply button 'Active' styles on keypress in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51413364/apply-button-active-styles-on-keypress-in-react)

I also read that string refs are not advised against now, sow I really don't know how to approach this.

Here is the link to my app: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/AldanaBRZ/drum-machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While string refs are discouraged. You can still use refs by using `React.createRef`

ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

You don't have to use refs even, you can give them all unique ids since they are unique anyways, and then whenever a key is pressed, you can check do a `if q is pressed, add pressed class to the q button`

Adding and removing classes on an HTML element in JS can be achieved by the following:

You can use `element.classList.add("pressed")` to achieve that. and `element.classList.remove("pressed")`

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. 

I haven't thought of changing the class identifying the button with the unique id it has. It sounds like a good idea and I'll try it. But once I target the element when a key is pressed, how do I add a class to it? And then can I remove the class with onKeyUp?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can use `classList.add("pressed")` to achieve that. and `classList.remove("pressed")`

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked! I had to use setTimeout to remove the class after a short time, and voilá!

Answer (score 0):

You can use styles to show button as pressed/unpressed, and manage pressed/unpressed event from state.
Please refer to link below. Neumorphism was a trending UI few months a go.

https://css-tricks.com/neumorphism-and-css/